# Setup infinite random CCMove

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Just a quick question– what is the most efficient way to setup an infinite movement sequence of a sprite? I am currently running with this:

```
-(void) pathToMove:(CCParticleSystemQuad*) system
{
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    int width = screenSize.width;
    int height = screenSize.height;
    float randX = arc4random() % width;
    float randY = arc4random() % (height - 200);

    CGPoint start = system.position;
    CGPoint end = ccp(randX, randY);

    float finalDistance = ccpDistance(start, end);
    float speedToMove = 500.0;

    float durationToMove = finalDistance / speedToMove;

    [system runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:durationToMove position:ccp(randX,randY)],[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(completedCurve:)],nil]];

}
-(void) completedCurve:(id) sender
{
    [self pathToMove:sender];   
}
```

But I worry that this might cause some strange zombies and or leaks by having an action call itself over and over. Is there a better way?

Comment: Should be fine. The old action will release itself, and the new action will be scheduled to run. You make the end point twice in this code. You also use CGPointMake and ccp, which both do the same thing. For consistency, why not stick with ccp for all cases.

Comment: Since posting I've done some digging. It appears that CCCallFunc are not safe with ARC, and that you should instead use CCCallBlocks. I cannot yet find why this is the case, however.

Comment: 1) use ARC 2) use blocks 3) don't assume, confirm. Callfunc's main problem is the void* data parameter in CCCallFuncND. The other call funcs work fine with ARC.